# Как сделать так, чтобы кнопка была сразу после label любой длины

Tags: c#, winforms

Допустим есть label, туда выводится текст, мне нужно, чтобы сразу после этого текста была кнопка. Например добавил я кучу слов и чтобы был батон в конце этого (Возможно это глупо, но такова моя хотелка). Как вариант меня сейчас просвятило немного, я мог бы добавить кнопку в конце и если текст будет слишком большой, когда он дойдет до кнопки, то он станет, допустим "StackOverfl..."Button. Вот так вот.

[image: Пример написанный от руки]

Comment: хотя бы эскизы этого "чуда" приложите к вопросу, не очень понятно как оно должно выглядеть. И что с много-строчным текстом планируется?

Comment: Нет не много, 1 строка в которой будет указан путь и я хочу чтобы после этого путя(?) был баттон с троеточием) В скриншоте нечего показывать, просто лейбл и кнопка. Повторюсь, хочу чтобы эта кнопка была сразу после лейбла, если такое возможно. Ну то что возможно - наверняка, но просто ли это, может это просто лишняя головная боль.  Текст однострочный. Когда упрется к барьеру нужно сделать конец троеточием.

Comment: Кажется я сам себя запутал. В общем, хочу чтобы когда лейбл дошел до кнопки он стал троеточием, щас приложу примерный скриншот(сделаю от руки)

Comment: А чтобы понять влезает текст или нет используйте [Graphics.MesureString](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring?view=netframework-4.8), и по факту подрезайте текст до приемлемой длины и содержания.

Comment: Лично мое мнение, если нужна экзотика - берете `UserControl` и на его основе ваяете собственный контрол. Можно наследоваться от `Label` и добавить туда все что нужно, но это более сложный путь.

Answer (score 1):

Можно применить способ, который общепринят в большинстве GUI-фреймворков. Вкладываем контролы в базовый, наподобие сетки. И настраиваем автоматическое изменение размеров и подстройку под них.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinForms
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Button button;
        private Label label;
        private TextBox textBox;
        private TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel;

        public Form1()
        {
            //InitializeComponent();

            textBox = new TextBox { Parent = this, Top = 50 };

            tableLayoutPanel = new TableLayoutPanel { Parent = this, ColumnCount = 2, RowCount = 1, AutoSize = true, AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink };
            label = new Label { Parent = tableLayoutPanel, AutoSize = true, Margin = new Padding(0, 5, 0, 0), };
            button = new Button { Parent = tableLayoutPanel, Left = label.Right, Margin = new Padding(0) };
            
            label.DataBindings.Add(nameof(Label.Text), textBox, nameof(TextBox.Text));
        }
    }
}
```

Здесь создаётся TableLayoutPanel, в него помещается Label и Button.
У TableLayoutPanel заданы две колонки и одна строка. Задано автоматическое изменение размеров.

Label тоже с автоматическим изменением размеров. Когда он расширяется или сжимается, он изменяет ширину колонки TableLayoutPanel, при этом кнопка во второй колонке тоже сдвигается.

---

Полезная ссылка: [Walkthrough: Arranging Controls on Windows Forms Using a TableLayoutPanel](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/walkthrough-arranging-controls-on-windows-forms-using-a-tablelayoutpanel). И слева в меню смотрите ссылки.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел такой выход:

```
button4.Location = new Point(label5.Size.Width, button4.Location.Y);
```

Вроде все работает так как я хотел.

Если нужно сделать, чтобы текст не уходил за рамки формы, то нужно указать в свойствах лейбла `AutoSize = false` и `AutoEllipsis = true`. AutoSize сделает лейблу границу, а AutoEllipsis сделает так, что когда текст дойдет до границы в конце текста будет троеточие.

Comment: Можно проще: `button.Left = label.Right;`. Ведь положение по вертикали не меняется.

Comment: И хорошо бы написать, где вы разместили этот код, в каком событии.